# What's wrong with this code that it doesn't compile?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, compilation, boolean

For some reason the true and false are considered "incompatible types".  Am I only suppose to run this through a boolean method?  What's wrong with it.

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length ; i++)
{
int val = (array[i] % 2);
if(val == 0)
array[i] = true;
else
array[i] = false;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you've declared `array` to be store some kind of numbers;  "true" and "false" aren't numbers.

Comment: what about closing this question as unclear ?

Comment: In what way is it unclear?

Comment: I agree, @Sage, although I'd hate to see Jon Skeet lose the chance for 100 more upvotes.

Comment: @DavidWallace we have to guess what type the array is declared as. As the question stands you have to guess if you want to try to help. It is fixable though.

Comment: The exception he is having clear why he is having and the type of the array is unknown. Yes we can assume many type but lets ask the reason: why a new created user intentionally didn't put the declaration code of `array`

Comment: @Tim Not really.  We know it's not `boolean[]`, which is really all that matters.

Comment: @DavidWallace ok fair enough. But the poster should presumably know that as well. Whatever.

Comment: @Tim, a new user posting a question without the declaration code of `array` which actually would answer the question and the IDE itself should have already told the answer.

Comment: @Sage it sounds like a user who is honestly confused, really.

Answer (score 6):

Well `array` is probably an `int[]`, given that you're using `array[i] % 2` and assigning the result to an `int`.

There's no conversion from `boolean` to `int`, so you can't store your result back in the `int[]` array. It's not clear what you're trying to do, but that's why it's not compiling.

---

**Aside**

If you had a separate `boolean[]` of the same size, that would work - although it would be more simply written as:

```
boolean[] even = new boolean[array.length];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    even[i] = (array[i] % 2) == 0;
}
```

Any time you find yourself with:

```
if (someCondition) {
    doSomething(true);
} else {
    doSomething(false);
}
```

you should consider refactoring it to:

```
doSomething(someCondition);
```

Comment: Jon, your answer was better when it was just the first two paragraphs - it answered the question completely and concisely.  Adding too much extra stuff is just going to confuse OP.

Comment: @DavidWallace: Will add a rule and indicate that it's an aside...

Answer (score 1):

Your array contains wrong types:

```
    int[] a = {1, 2, 4};
    boolean[] b = {true, false};

    b[0] = 1; //error
    a[0] = 1; //ok
```